# Can't use kendoComboBox in kendoGrid

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to bind combobox into kendo grid

Please give me example code grid that have bind combobox from database

```
 var provinces = $("#ddlProvince").kendoComboBox({
                    placeholder: "Choose Province",
                    dataTextField: "pname",
                    dataValueField: "pcode",
                    dataSource:data_province
                }).data("kendoComboBox");

<div id="gridData"></div>
```

Comment: Did my answer resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is called custom editor, you can find some example here http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html

Link your field to specific editor

```
  { field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "160px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor,
```

Define your editor

```
 function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                    $('<input required data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                            autoBind: false,
                            dataSource: {
                                type: "odata",
                                transport: {
                                    read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
```

Now when you click edit on specific row, custom editor of your choice is appended.